# When I try to start my code it says unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

So i'm a brad new coder and took my first class today and I thought it was sooo fun so I decided to do it at home and on the learning course page one of the activities was making a game and it would help me step by step but then I came across a problem where when I stated the program a pop up would say unindent does not match any outer indentation level and so I looked for problems and then I copied the code from the course and it still doesn't work can somebody please help me thanks!

```py
store = raw_input("\nDo you want to buy weapons? (yes or no)\n\n").lower()
       if store == "yes":
    print "\nWEAPON\t\tCOST\n"

for items in WEAPONS_STORE:
print items, "\t\t", WEAPONS_STORE[items], "\n"

print "\nYou have", gold, "gold\n\n"
weapon_purchase = raw_input("Which weapon would you like to buy?\n\n").lower() 

game()
```

Comment: Add the content of the code here instead of an image

Comment: the indentation does look incorrect

Comment: I can see the indentation problem in your `for:`. I don't want to dishearten you on learning programming, but Stack Overflow isn't really the place to ask questions on your first day; this is supposed to be a repository of questions and answers that will help many people (you will become one of the people it helps). It's not for debugging.

Comment: if/for/while and any other loops/ statements require 4 spaces on the next line this is how python knows that the following line of code is in said statement.... Also please post your code in the actual question not a picture

Comment: @JoeA probably just being pedantic but the 4 spaces are just a recommendation, not _required_; 1 space of indentation is enough for each level, it's just totally illegible. File picked at random from [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/distribute/all_reduce_test.py) to illustrate; they have a policy of 2 space indentation

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for the clear up I appreciate it I'm  just used to do doing 4 spaces. Also nice tensorflow example !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the indentation is just messed up a little bit, not sure if they went over it in your class but a `:` should tell you that the code that follows should be indented, anything involved in an `if` statement or `for` loop etc should be nested inside.

```
store = raw_input("\nDo you want to buy weapons? (yes or no)\n\n").lower()
if store == "yes":
    print "\nWEAPON\t\tCOST\n"

for items in WEAPONS_STORE:
    print items, "\t\t", WEAPONS_STORE[items], "\n"
    print "\nYou have", gold, "gold\n\n"

weapon_purchase = raw_input("Which weapon would you like to buy?\n\n").lower() 
game()
```

Note how everything under the for loop is all inline because it's nested inside the for loop, it helps to also visualize what code is going to run when you get to the foor loop.
Also I think you're using python 2, so if you're learning to code in python I'd recommend you switch over to python 3 now and start learning that instead.